# most efficient way to select duplicate rows with max timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I have a table called `t`, which is like

```
id  content  time
1     'a'     100
1     'a'     101
1     'b'     102
2     'c'     200
2     'c'     201
```

`id` are duplicate, and for the same `id`, content could also be duplicate. Now I want to select for each id the rows with max timestamp, which would be

```
id  content  time
1      'b'    102
2      'c'    201
```

And this is my current solution:

```sql
select t1.id, t1.content, t1.time 
from (
  select id, content, time from t 
) as t1 
right join (
  select id, max(time) as time from t group by id
) as t2 
on t1.id = t2.id and t1.time = t2.time;
```

But this looks inefficient to me. Because theoretically when `select id, max(time) as time from t group by id` is executed, the rows I want have already been located. The `right join` brings extra O(n^2) time cost, which seems unnecessary.

So is there any more efficient way to do it, or anything that I missunderstand?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, content, time
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id, time DESC;
```

On Postgres, this is usually the most performant way to write your query, and it should outperform `ROW_NUMBER` and other approaches.

The following index might speed up this query:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (id, time DESC, content);
```

This index, if used, would let Postgres rapidly find, for each `id`, the record having the latest time.  This index also covers the `content` column.

Comment: is `order by` necessary, considering I just want a max?

Comment: Yes `ORDER BY` is very necessary to make `DISTINCT ON` work.  If you need some _other_ ordering, then you may subquery and add a different order by clause.

Comment: @taotsi without the ORDER BY, how would it know you want the max?  It needs to informed of that somehow.  With DISTINCT ON, ordering is the mechanism which informs it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I mean, generally, sorting takes O(nlogn) time, while finding the max takes only O(n). I just want the max, and don't care the second max or the third max... If you're doing this using some dataframe library like pandas, you can find the max without sorting. I wonder if SQL can do that

Comment: @taotsi I think what is you're looking for then is an _index_ on your table which would allow for log(n) search time, for each `id` value, q.v. my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.content, a.time FROM t AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a.content, MAX(a.time) AS time FROM t
    GROUP BY a.content
) AS b ON a.content = b.content AND a.time = b.time
```

Comment: `content` could be very long strings. I think it's less efficient to compare `content` than `id`